# Extract RGB32 Byte Data from IMFSample

Tags: winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I have [IMFSample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms702192(v=vs.85).aspx) data that is **RGB32**, and I want to convert this format to BMP or I want to extract the actual RGB32 bytes and save to file and then using some external tool convert to BMP or any other format.

So question is how can I get **RGB32** data from `IMFSample`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IMFMediaBuffer interface can be taken via the ConvertToContiguousBuffer call (as mentioned in another answer).
Additionally, the IMFMediaBuffer can be queried for IMF2DBuffer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms699894(v=vs.85).aspx.
It's Lock2D method is more convenient and faster when accessing the raw data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473821(v=vs.85).aspx. The pointer to the data and the pitch returned by Lock2D could be used in a SetDiBitsToDevice call for example.

Furthermore, you could also query the IMFMediaBuffer for IMFDXGIBuffer to access the underlying DXGI surface as ID3D11Texture2D, if the buffer comes from a hardware accelerated decoder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447901(v=vs.85).aspx.
You can access the raw data in the DXGI buffer via the Map/Unmap DirectX 11 methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457(v=vs.85).aspx

You could also query the IMFMediaBuffer for IMFGetService and obtain the IDirect3DSurface9 interface from it. The underlying data could be accessed via it's Lock/Unlock methods. 
Here is the preferred order for accessing the raw data in the IMFSample's IMFMediaBuffer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530112(v=vs.85).aspx
The IMFDXGIBuffer could be queried if the IMFGetService / IDirect3DSurface9  fails.

Comment: Great answer. A further inquiry… if `IMF2DBuffer` and `IMFDXGIBuffer` are both available, which is preferred and what are the tradeoffs? I'm currently using DXGI to facilitate `ID3D11DeviceContext.CopyResource`; the destination RTV is a persistent `ID3D11Texture2D` also shared as `IDirect3DTexture9` for `D3DImage`/WPF video backbuffer. Works great, staying mostly on the GPU, I believe. Now if the `IMF2DBuffer` is lockable as you posit, I assume that would be a CPU access scenario instead? Map/Unmap would thus be slow? Am I missing anything? What would be a compelling case for IMF2DBuffer?

Comment: One other note. Prior to the method I just described, I was changing the `D3DImage` backbuffer **on every frame** by directly stuffing in the underlying resource of the `IMFSample`. In this case, I had to set `MF_SA_D3D11_SHARED_WITHOUT_MUTEX` on the `IMFTopology` to allow sharing of each incoming `ID3D11Texture2D` into a `IDirect3DTexture9`. This worked well also, and had a happy feeling of doing no copying at all... until I discovered that the penalty was hiding in the unorthodox use of `D3DImage.SetBackBuffer`, i.e. *per-frame*. Can you comment on any contrasts between this method vs above?

Comment: I think it depends on your needs. If you need a IDirect3DTexture9 then why not query IMFMediaBuffer for IMFGetService and obtain the IDirect3DSurface9? If it is not supported then yes you should resort to sharing and/or copying. I'm not sure if any of MF_SA_D3D11_SHARED_WITHOUT_MUTEX and ID3D11DeviceContext.CopyResource would be (significantly) faster (at all) though.

Comment: I guess my point was that the design decision is not so simple if we aren't so passive about accepting whatever's handed to us later on. Isn't it the case that *whether* `IDirect3DSurface9` is "supported" by a IMFMediaBuffer--or not--is *determined* by whether the sample allocator created the underlying ID3D11Texture2D with `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED `(or not)?
For the purposes MF MediaSession, the flag I mentioned (`MF_SA_D3D11_SHARED_WITHOUT_MUTEX`) is supposed to influence or encourage that.

Comment: No, that's not the case. The decoder can decide to support either ID3D11Texture2D  or IDirect3DSurface9  or both. IMFMediaBuffer should always be queryiunterface'ed to obtain the available interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

1. [`IMFSample::ConvertToContiguousBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698917) gets you `IMFMediaBuffer` interface with data
2. [`IMFMediaBuffer::Lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970366) gets you access to raw data

Make sure to unlock when you're done. Then release COM interface pointers as usually.

Comment: what should I do if I get the raw data?